# RhythmBox Plugins Menu

Tags: 13.10, rhythmbox

I have just installed RhythmBox via the Software Centre (2.99.1) but either for love nor money does my UI look like the images in the screenshots; I'm trying to hook up to my DLNA NAS.  I have the Grilo 0.2 plugin installed (also via software Centre) but the edit menu in RhythmBox does not contain an entry for "plug-ins".  From what I have read I need to enable the plug-in, but have no idea how to get to the configuration screen.

Assistance greatly appreciated.

thanks

paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new versions of Rhythmbox do not have an edit menu at all. There is a single menu, and `Plugins` is an option in it. It is now using the integrated menus feature of GNOME 3.x. Under Unity, there is a single menu that appears in the global menu when Rhythmbox is focused, titled `Rhythmbox`.